# How to link the form from the audience/inbox tab in mailchimp?

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js, mailchimp

I'm struggling with linking the inbox mailchimp form with next.js. Such type of link: https://xxx.list-manage.com/contact-form?u=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&form_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
I was trying to use react-mailchimp-subscribe, but I get the CORB error in console. Please, help

Here is my code:

```
const Sponsor = () => {
const url = `https://us10.list-manage.com/contact-form? u=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAILCHIMP_U}&form_id=9${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAILCHIMP_ID}`;
  return (
    <Layout>
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <div className={styles.text}>
            <h1>{SPONSOR_PAGE.heading}</h1>
            <h3>{SPONSOR_PAGE.subheading}</h3>
            <p>{SPONSOR_PAGE.description}</p>
          </div>
            <MailchimpSubscribe
                url={url}
                render={({ subscribe, status, message }) => (
                    <CustomForm
                        status={status} 
                        message={message}
                        onValidated={formData => subscribe(formData)}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

````
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState('');
  const [messageInput, setMessageInput] = useState('');
  const [subscription, setSubscription] = useState(false);

  const [state, setState] = useState('idle')
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null)

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    onValidated({
      MERGE0: email,
    });
  }

  return (
    <form
      className={styles.containerForm}
      onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
    >
       ...my fields here
    </form>
  );
};

export default Sponsor```
````